# Why is the invocation of a named function considered anonymous in chrome dev tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have a function called doStuff
    function doStuff(prop){
        console.log(prop)
    }
I invoke the function like so:
    doStuff('boop');

**Question:** Why does chrome dev tools consider the `doStuff('boop')` invocation `line 4` an `(anonymous function)`?

[image]

[image]

Comment: isn't it that the call (`doStuff('boop')`) is being made from an anonymous function?

Comment: I never inserted the wrapping parenthesis in the script.js?  are you telling me the browser does?

Comment: No, if you're calling it from top, then there is no caller, so the dev tool considers it as an anonymous function.

Comment: What do you mean from the "top"  ?

Comment: "the top" here would be the execution process that occurs when the browser have finished loading the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#call-stack-panel

> The **Call Stack** panel displays the complete execution path that led to
>   the point where code was paused

So the "`(anonymous function)`" you get, refers to the caller of the function.

In your example, you are calling it from the "top" execution process, which occurs when the browsers have finished loading the scripts. Thus, there is no caller, the devTools then considers it as an `anonymous function` call.